# HMAC in C++ that outputs the same value in Java

Tags: java, c++, hmac

I am unable to get the same output from HMAC in C++ like the one i wrote in java, they have different output.

## Java:

```
private static byte[] hmac_sha(String crypto, byte[] keyBytes, byte[] text) {
    try {
        Mac hmac;
        hmac = Mac.getInstance(crypto);
        SecretKeySpec macKey = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "RAW");
        hmac.init(macKey);
        return hmac.doFinal(text);
    } catch (GeneralSecurityException gse) {
        throw new UndeclaredThrowableException(gse);
    }
}
```

C++:

```
BYTE *key = (BYTE *)encodedSeed.data();
    BYTE digest[20];
    const char *message = encodedTime.data();
    CHMAC_SHA1 HMAC;
    HMAC.HMAC_SHA1((BYTE *)message, strlen(message), key, sizeof(key), digest);

    wstring finalDigest;

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++){

        finalDigest.push_back(std::btowc(digest[i]));
    }


    return finalDigest;
```

Comment: In the second one, you are specify HMAC-SHA1.  But what versi. Of HMAC is being used in the first one?  Do we know that SHA1 is under the hood, or could it be another hash function?

Comment: yes , Crypto is a fixed variable that maps to HMACSHA1

Comment: You know what is the problem, In java, hash byte[] has negative values while in C++ because all hmac_sha1 implemented using unsigned char , i am always getting positive values and thus , their hash values are different

Comment: How can i create hmac sha1 in c++ that is equivalent to java, can anybody show me some code for this

Comment: Trying to force C++ to behave like backwards Java (that lacks an unsigned type) is the wrong direction, but if you really want to do it, then copy to signed char array and that should make the conversion automatic.